# sphinx-build cannot generate epub output

Tags: 10.10, epub

On Ubuntu 10.10 when I run the command `sphinx-build -b epub -d _build/doctrees   . _build/epub`, I see the following output:

`Running Sphinx v0.6.6`

Sphinx error:
Builder name epub not registered
make: *** [epub] Error 1

It could just be a missing package, but I don't know which one. The sphinx documentation page doesn't say that the epub builder is only available in a later release.

Comment: You could ask on the Sphinx mailing list.

Comment: Have you enabled the epub support? It's disabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx 0.6.6 doesn't have epub support. It was added on version 1.0. You might want to check the [changelog](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/changes.html) for more details.